# Solaris 10: How to remove devices from a zpool with /usr currently mounted?

Tags: solaris, zfs

I use Solaris 10 on SPARC. I have /usr legacy mounted on a zpool 'usr-pool'.

I now need to move some of the devices in usr-pool to another zpool which is running out of room.

What is the safest way for me to do this? I already know that (since my zpool is not mirrored) I need to destroy and recreate the zpool. I know how to backup and restore a zfs snapshot. However... I'm stumped on how to unmount usr-pool without losing access to the commands I need on /usr to complete the backup/restore.

Cursory research indicated that I should boot to OpenBoot (init 0) and then 'boot cdrom -s'. I did this but none of the zpools are accessible on that runlevel.

I also read I could just copy /usr to another location, symlink /usr to that location, then do my backup/restore. Is that safe to do?

I would appreciate some guidance.

S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately ZFS does not currently support shrinking the pool.

Since you already mentioned that your intention is to destroy and recreate the pool, here's what to do. But first...

#### WARNING: DESTROYING YOUR POOLS WILL DESTROY YOUR DATA. YOUR BLOOD IS ON YOUR OWN HEAD.

Now, with that out of the way:

1. Create a new pool mounted on `/usr-new`
2. Use `zfs-send` from a snapshot of `usr-pool` to `usr-new` (You also need to account for any descendent datasets).
3. `zfs unmount usr-new`.
4. Change the mountpoint of `usr-new` to `/usr` (it may complain, but should work. Check with `zfs get mountpoint usr-new`)
5. Set `usr-pool` (i.e., the old one) to use legacy mounting with `zfs set mountpoint=legacy usr-pool` (this will cause it to not be auto mounted at boot but also not immediately unmount it).
6. Reboot.

You'll boot up with the new `usr-new` mounted on `/usr` and the old `usr-pool` not mounted. You are then free to destroy `usr-pool` and reuse disks as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am pretty sure would have worked but unfortunately I wrecked my /etc/vfstab before reading this... So that created a whole other problem. :)

Comment: also, consider booting to single-user mode before you make these changes.

Comment: @TimKennedy: One would certainly want to vet the entire process on a test system before attempting it on production, but these instructions are written to be run safely on a live system.

Comment: @bahamat one would hope so, eh? :)

Comment: @TimKennedy: No need to hope. They *are*. I've done things similar to this on live systems. It's safe. I don't know the OP's environment well enough to give specific exact steps, but using these steps as a template and vetting on a non-production system that mimics the original it's very safe to do this live, with the only downtime being the reboot.